# Using r,c notation in interop.exel formulas

Tags: c#, excel, interop, formula

I want to create a formula using interop to sum values in column 33 using the row and column rather than AG1:AG33.  can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

To sum the entire column:

```
myRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C33)";
```

Or, to sum only the first five cells:

```
myRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C33:R5C33);
```